# Does the interaction between 2 photons change its traveling directions?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, photoelectric-effect, laser-interaction

As I understand from the Hong-Ou-Mandle effect, the interaction between 2 photons is possible. Can 2 Photons interact with each other in free space? Suppose that the 2 photons met in the spacetime with same (frequency, phase, etc.); Will that affect the traveling direction of the 2 photons in spacetime after the interaction?

Comment: There's a wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics

Comment: Thank you.. but my question is different. Im asking if theoretically the interaction is possible between 2 photons with normal energy.